# Azure Active Directory search in hebrew

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

Using the Graph API I am attempting to load a list of Azure Active Directory Users according to their `department`. I do it like this:

```
public List<User> GetUsersByDepartment(string dept)
{
    QueryOperationResponse<User> response;
    var users = DirectoryService.users;
    users = (DataServiceQuery<User>)(users.Where(user => user.department.Equals(dept)));
    response = users.Execute() as QueryOperationResponse<User>;
    List<User> deptUsers = response.ToList();

    return deptUsers;
}
```

If `dept` is in English, I get corresponding results. If `dept` is in Hebrew, I get no results at all... The following works but **requires a full load of the Users list**:

```
public List<User> GetUsersByDepartment(string dept)
{
    var users = DirectoryService.users.ToList();
    List<User> deptUsers = users.Where(user => user.department.Equals(dept)).ToList();

    return deptUsers;
}
```

Does the Azure Active Directory support searches in Hebrew? If so, what am I missing in my first example? Could there be a setting in the Azure Active Directory itself?

Comment: I am having the same troubles myself with it. No one seems to have an anwser when it comes to azure. Usually globalization in the web.config should fix it but in this case since this is not directly related to the asp itself there is no way to fix it but try and configure azure differently.

Comment: I think that due to how the Graph API performs a REST call to a service, it is a matter of handling languages on the service's side. I'm looking into alternatives like simply not performing searches in Hebrew, or even manually syncing a copy of the data to a local DB and only working through the AAD/Graph API for updates. I don't like it though.

Comment: I fixed my problem by manually entering my data through the azure portal. Encoding issues. But I had file problems, not AD.

Comment: This was service-side issue with Unicode that should now work if the department name is Unicode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue in the service side that has now been fixed.

You should be able to verify this easily at https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net. Just sign in to a directory with users with Unicode characters in the DisplayName (or department), and try the REST query:

```
https://graph.windows.net/<your domain name>/users()?$filter=startswith(displayName,'%C3%80%C3%A0%C3%88')`
```

(Changing the encoded Unicode characters to whatever you're looking for.)